# R: lubridate returns NA –unexpectedly

Tags: r, lubridate

I discovered a rather unexpected behavior of lubridate.
The following R code returns NAs instead of '2010-10-17 08:00:00':

```
library(lubridate);
as.POSIXct("2010-10-17 07:59:01") + seconds(59);
as.POSIXct("2010-10-17 07:59:30") + seconds(30);
```

Whereas the following snippet returns the expected value ('2010-10-17 07:59:00'):

```
as.POSIXct("2010-10-17 07:58:01") + seconds(59);
as.POSIXct("2010-10-17 07:58:30") + seconds(30);
```

Is this a bug in lubridate or do I simply have to RTFM more thoroughly?! :)

**UPDATE**: Used software: Gnu R v 3.0.2, lubridate 1.3.3

**UPDATE 2**: Using *dseconds* instead of *seconds* solves this issue.

Correct result is calculated by:

```
as.POSIXct("2010-10-17 07:58:01") + dseconds(59);
as.POSIXct("2010-10-17 07:58:30") + dseconds(30);
```

Comment: Looks like it could be a timezone and/or daylight saving time issue.

Comment: what class did you create `"2010-10-17 07:59:01"` with (as a check)?

Comment: @Joshua: Thanks. But you can change the month to any valid value and the behavior stays the same...

Comment: @RScriv: I don't understand your question. It's just a string...

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I tried the following:
_ymd_hms("2010-01-17 07:59:01") + seconds(59);_
Which also returns _NA_. :/

Comment: the `base` method uses `strptime`.  `lubridate` does not.  Try `unclass` on the string then see what happens.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich take a peek at my answer's latest edit.  What's up with 8PM exactly?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: it's 8am, and I have no idea. Seems to be an issue with lubridate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final Edit:  known bug:  https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues/188

I found the bug, as it were:  Apparently the `POSIXct`-class object will allow you to modify its `seconds` portion, but there's no "carry" function, so if you force the total seconds to exceed 59,  it gives up.

```
Rgames> as.POSIXct("2010-10-17 07:59:30")->dfoo
Rgames> dfoo
[1] "2010-10-17 07:59:30 EDT"

Rgames> second(dfoo)
[1] 30
Rgames> second(dfoo)<-second(dfoo)+10
Rgames> dfoo
[1] "2010-10-17 07:59:40 EDT"
Rgames> second(dfoo)<-second(dfoo)+seconds(10)
Rgames> dfoo
[1] "2010-10-17 07:59:50 EDT"
Rgames> second(dfoo)<-second(dfoo)+seconds(10)
Rgames> dfoo
[1] NA
```

What the intended use of the `lubridate::seconds`  and `second` functions are, I dunno, but clearly this ain't the way to go :-( .

EDIT: I kept playing, with `dfoo` as above and `dbar <-  as.POSIXct("2010-10-17 07:59:30",tz='GMT')` .  I could add arbitrary seconds to `dbar` w/o problem.  Further, I used `with_tz` to switch the time zones for both `dfoo` and `dbar`, and regardless of the zone assigned, could successfully add arbitrary seconds.
This leads me to wonder just what the [redacted] `as.POSIXct` does with the default `tz=''` argument!

EDIT 2:  hey, look:

```
Rgames> as.POSIXct("2010-10-17 07:59:30")->dfoo
Rgames> dfoo + seconds(55)
[1] "2010-10-17 08:00:25 EDT"
Rgames> dfoo + seconds(30)
[1] NA
Rgames> dfoo + seconds(31)
[1] "2010-10-17 08:00:01 EDT"
Rgames> dfoo + seconds(29)
[1] "2010-10-17 07:59:59 EDT"
```

Comment: Not sure if it's the reason, but the package description says it allows fractions of a second, should you so desire them.

Comment: Reading through the article at http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/03/do-more-with-dates-and-times-in-r-with-lubridate-1-1-0/ it seems like `lubridate::seconds` is a period, and the article implies it's precise on purpose, but `lubridate::dseconds` is treated as a duration, which is by design precise, so when trying to add an imprecise time to the object with rollover, maybe because of the imprecision?  The docs aren't clear, but it's something to keep in mind.